# I don't understand what the syntax should be for this datagridview new action invoke command

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, invoke

I'm trying to generate a program to monitor a database file for changes and to return the last 10 entries in a datagridview list.

I've searched a mountain of Google references relating to Invoke and New Action and tried various iterations of code, but as I don't fully understand the Invoke New Action statement even after reading Microsoft documents and forum references, I can't make the syntax correct.

```
Private Sub UpdateDgvThread()
    RemoveHandler watcher.Changed, AddressOf OnChanged
    DataGridView1.Invoke(New Action(AddressOf UpdateDgv))
    AddHandler watcher.Changed, AddressOf OnChanged
End Sub
```

I get a 'Too few type arguments to 'System.Action(Of T)' error when running the program and the closest I've come is changing the error line to

```
DataGridView1.Invoke(New Action(Of ????)(AddressOf UpdateDgv))
```

which seems to be a corrected syntax(?) but I don't know what the ???? should be.

Comment: Have you checked https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.action?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: Also https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.action-1?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: What is the method signature of `UpdateDgv`? Does it have any arguments?

Comment: Thanks Mary, unfortunately I didn't see an applicable reference to vb.net, only C#. Djv, there were no arguments, it just sets the Datasource to nothing and refills from an access database defined elsewhere when called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to pass the address of a method with arguments into the constructor of `Action` (the version with no generic type arguments).

Instead, you should state the type(s) of the argument(s) to `UpdateDgv` by using the correct constructor

```
New Action(Of T, ...)()
```

Here are three possible versions of `UpdateDgv`, and their corresponding `Invoke` calls.

```
Private Sub UpdateDgv0()
End Sub

Private Sub UpdateDgv1(arg1 As Object)
End Sub

Private Sub UpdateDgv2(arg1 As Object, arg2 As EventArgs)
End Sub

Private Sub UpdateDgvThread()
    DataGridView1.Invoke(New Action(AddressOf UpdateDgv0))
    DataGridView1.Invoke(New Action(Of Object)(AddressOf UpdateDgv1), New Object())
    DataGridView1.Invoke(New Action(Of Object, EventArgs)(AddressOf UpdateDgv2), New Object(), New EventArgs())
End Sub
```

Another option is to just use an anonymous method to wrap around the call to `UpdateDgv`, and you won't see the `Action` constructor at all. This works because `Sub()` satisfies `Delegate`, just like `Action`, but the function pointer `AddressOf` alone does not.

```
DataGridView1.Invoke(Sub() UpdateDgv0())
DataGridView1.Invoke(Sub() UpdateDgv1(New Object()))
DataGridView1.Invoke(Sub() UpdateDgv2(New Object(), New EventArgs()))
```

Since you're using .NET 3.0, you won't see the parameterless `Action`, which was introduced in 3.5. You could make your own Action delegate pretty simply. Adding this to your original code would also have solved the problem

```
Private Delegate Sub Action()
```

It is superior to the `DataGridView1.Invoke(Sub() UpdateDgv())` approach because it involves one less call on the stack trace (though the compiler may optimize it away, I'm not sure).

Comment: Thank you for all of the information, I played around with the variations of the Invoke Action statements you suggested but could get none of them to work with my code. What did work in the end was replacing the Invoke Action statement with the Sub statement so the final line read as - DataGridView1.Invoke(Sub() UpdateDgv()) - and worked perfectly, thank you.

Comment: @TonyFaiers Glad it worked, but it's odd that with the method `Private Sub UpdateDgv()` you were unable to do `DataGridView1.Invoke(New Action(AddressOf UpdateDgv))`. That should definitely work. Unless you are using .NET Framework version 2.0 or 3.0. Framework version 3.5 introduced the parameterless `Action`.

Comment: That last sentence explained everything, the code was set to .NET 3.0 as it was aimed at a being an application to run on an old Windows XP machine, this would explain why that one line didn't work to start with!

Comment: @TonyFaiers you can also make your own Action() delegate `Delegate Sub Action()`. I updated my answer